# how to count special character in string javascript function which accept only like @ #

Tags: javascript

in my project I have task to  user entered character to be count and display the count it is working fine but i want to add regex which only allowed special char

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function countChars(countfrom,displayto)
{
  var len = document.getElementById(countfrom).value.length;
  document.getElementById(displayto).innerHTML = len;
}
</script>


<label>Enter Character</label><br>
<textarea id="data" cols="40" rows="5"
onkeyup="countChars('data','charcount');" onkeydown="countChars('data','charcount');"
onmouseout="countChars('data','charcount');">
</textarea><br>
<span id="charcount">0</span> 
</html>
```

Comment: you can use match javascript property

Comment: no can you explain me please

Comment: see this link : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

Comment: but i want to return count

Comment: var res = str.match(/@/g).length;

Comment: does it worked?

Comment: Don't bother with regular expressions unless you were asked to : it doesn't have any magic token for "special characters" so you'll still be down to listing them, but now you'll also have the problem of handling the regex syntax and specialized methods instead of simple string / characters operations. Regex is a great tool, but certainly not an universal one.

Answer (score 1):

A working Example:

```html
<label>Enter Character</label><br>
<textarea id="data" cols="40" rows="5"
onkeyup="countChar(this, '@', 'charcount');" onkeydown="countChar(this, '@', 'charcount');"
onmouseout="countChar(this, '@', 'charcount');">
</textarea><br>
<span id="charcount">0</span> 


<script>
function countChar(container, char, targetId) {
  target = document.getElementById(targetId);
  var regEx = new RegExp(char, 'g');
  var matches = container.value.match(regEx);
  
  if(matches) {
   target.innerHTML = matches.length;
  }
}  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one, this matches all special characters

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function countChars()
{
    var textarea  = document.getElementById('data').value;
    var specialCharacters = textarea.match(/[@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/g);

    if(specialCharacters == null) return;

    document.getElementById('charcount').innerHTML = specialCharacters.length;
}
</script>


<label>Enter Character</label><br>
<textarea id="data" cols="40" rows="5"
onkeyup="countChars();" onkeydown="countChars();"
onmouseout="countChars();"></textarea>
<span id="charcount">0</span>
</html>
```